# Package a SharePoint solution from the DTE

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, powershell, envdte

Is there a way to package a SharePoint solution in a .wsp file from the Visual Studio dte?

I can build the solution with the following command:

```
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution")
```

But that doesn't package the project.

Note: I was trying to do this with Powershell/PowerConsole, but it would be the same as if I was accessing the $dte some other way.

Comment: try `$dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.Package")` or `$dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.BuildDeploymentPackage")`

Comment: @chrixian Your first suggestion worked. If you enter it as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.Package")`